# Mathematical status of Jansen's linkage

Tags: calculus, geometry, classical-mechanics

Does [Jansen's linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jansen%27s_linkage) mechanism achieve a genuinely flat segment of the foot's cycle or merely an approximation?

[image]

Dimensions of mechanism given here, though presumably the actual measurements require more precise definition.

[image]

Comment: This linkage is a modification of the Peaucellier–Lipkin linkage. With properly chosen bar-lengths, it will draw an exact straight line segment. However, the numbers appearing in the picture are likely to produce only an approximately linear motion.

Answer (score 3):

Simply because the coordinates  of all points are linked by polynomial equations (obtainable from Pythagoras), the curve is given by an algebraic equation. Such an equation *could* describe a line, but nothing that is partly curved and partly a line.

Comment: ... so, since the "leg" also traces a curve above the "ground", the curve cannot be linear...?

Comment: @paulgarrett that would be my argument, similar to the [Chebyshev Lambda Mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_Lambda_Mechanism) or [Hoecken's linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeckens_linkage).  I have a working model of a Jansen Strandbeest involving $12$ of these linkages and it works impressively with the right amount of wind

Comment: @Henry, though, now that I think about it, there is no a-priori reason the curve should be _irreducible_... E.g., $x\cdot (x^2+y^2-1)=0$. How to argue that a mechanism cannot trace a semi-circle and the diameter...?

Comment: This is actually quite wrong as it assumes that the curve traced by a linkage is irreducible. The famous inversor is a standard counter example: One irreducible component is linear and another is circular. Also, curve traced by a general linkage and only semialgebraic.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Is there a link or some other reference to support this?

Comment: @geotheory: See for instance https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040938301000349. They observe that the "curve" drawn by the P-L inversor has several "bad" irreducible components: One is 2-dimensional and another is 1-dimensional but nonlinear. They add several "bells and whistles" to the inversor to get rid of the bad components.  (These issues with the inversor were known in the engineering literature earlier.) I suggest ignoring the algebro-geometric preliminaries and start reading in section 3.1. Then jump to section 6.4.

Comment: They add the "hook" AED to the inversor to eliminate the nonlinear component.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks. Well I scanned that paper but alas there's zero chance I'll grok it. Feel free to post your comment (as is) as an answer and let the community vote on it :)